# vNext EF7 code first migration. Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core

i decided to learn a new asp.net. I started writing, i made a model, i want to do the migration and i see this:

in console:

```
c:\...>k ef migration add init_pracownicy -c PracownicyDbContext
```

and return:

```
    k : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the 
LoaderExceptions property for more information.
At line:1 char:1
+ k ef
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.Reflecti...re information.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Ru
ntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.TryGetEntryPoint(Assembly assembly, IServiceProvider 
serviceProvider, Object& instance, MethodInfo& entryPoint)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider 
serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I searched in google but did not find an answer. (Maybe bad looking).
Please some help.

Answer (score 0):

This means loaded assemblies and referenced assemblies have a mismatch.

There are multiple possible solutions.

1. If you compiled with Debug mode and trying to deploy older dlls from release (or vice versa), just check and ensure the same directory is used for build and deployment
2. Try setting "Copy Local" attribute to "true" on your project references

Answer (score 0):

I instal VS2015 CTP. I created a new project. That's what I had already written a rewrite to the new project. And everything works. Problem solved. (I had previously vs2015 preview)